# What is my pet tortoise' species?

Tags: species-identification, species

I got this tortoise from my uncle. He said that it wandered into his yard. Found in Khon Kaen, Thailand during the summer.[image][image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn yourself your first badge. Have a nice stay!

Answer (score 1):

It is a **Burmese brown mountain tortoise - *Manouria Emys Emys*** [image]
 I differentiated it from a burmese black mountain turtle by this [method](http://www.chelonia.org/Articles/diffmanouria.htm).